# Deployment with Chef

Tags: deployment, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am using the chef resource "deploy_revision" to deploy a python code on my nodes. I started this initially for a dev environment but now slowly there is a need for this to expand and i am not sure - if this is a good choice. Below is the code.

```
data_bag = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("#{node.chef_environment}", "#{node.chef_environment}")

deploy_revision "/opt/mount/#{node[:application_name]}" do
  repo "#{node[:application_repo]}"
  user "deployer"
  keep_releases 10
  action :deploy
  migrate false
  symlink_before_migrate.clear
  create_dirs_before_symlink
  purge_before_symlink.clear
  symlinks.clear
  symlinks {}
  notifies :restart, "service[abc]"
end
```

This pulls down the new code whenever there is one, during the automatic chef-run every 30mins on the nodes. This is cool but not so cool in other nodes which are not a part of the development environment. I have 4 environments:
dev
test
stage 
prod

If i create 4 remote branches on the git, Is there a way on how to make this deploy from specific branch on specific environments? Something like, the dev nodes deploy the dev remote branch, test deploys the test remote branch and so on.. This way, i can put a gate on the auto deploys that happening every 30mins. i referred the chef docs, there is this "deploy_branch" but i not sure it just says its the same as "deploy_revision". 
https://docs.chef.io/resource_deploy.html#layout-modifiers

There is an attribute branch available as per the chef document. So adding the attribute like is what i need?

```
deploy_revision "/opt/mount/#{node[:application_name]}" do
  repo "#{node[:application_repo]}"
  user "deployer"
  branch "node.chef_environment"    
  keep_releases 10
  action :deploy
  migrate false
  symlink_before_migrate.clear
  create_dirs_before_symlink
  purge_before_symlink.clear
  symlinks.clear
  symlinks {}
  notifies :restart, "service[abc]"
end
```

Then, i came across this bug report (closed): https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-5084. It seems to be specifying branches with the attribute, "revision". So, can i use this attribute with the node environment as the parameter? Like this

```
revision "node.chef_environments"
```

If you guys, think deployment using chef is not a good idea. Do you think- i should look out for Capistrano?

Answer (score 0):

we do this all the time.  Just add:

```
deploy_revision '/path' do
  ...
  revision node['chef_environment']
  ...
end
```

Or in our case, we calculate the branch from the `chef_environment`

```
deploy_revision '/path' do
  ...
  revision node['chef_environment'].match(/develop|staging|production|test/)[0]
  ...
end
```

Comment: what is difference between branch "node.chef_environment"   & revision node['chef_environment'] .. I am trying to make the deploy_revison deploy the remote dev,test,staging, production branches to the nodes which belongs to dev,test,staging, production environments in my chef cookbook

Comment: node['chef_environment'] is the same thing as node.chef_environment.  `revision` is just the attribute on the deploy_revision resource.

Comment: i have modified the code as this  http://pastebin.com/GUB2rh1Z  .. But the chef still deploys the code that is on the origin/dev branch of the repository. I am expecting it to deploy the code in origin/test branch as the node belongs to the test environment of chef.  The chef log just says "fetch updates for origin"

Comment: You'll need to take a look at your log output.  It should show you what revision it is using, and that will give you a better idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me.

```
deploy_revision "/opt/mount/#{node[:application_name]}" do
  repo "#{node[:application_repo]}"
  user "deployer"
  revision node.chef_environment    
  keep_releases 10
  action :deploy
  migrate false
  symlink_before_migrate.clear
  create_dirs_before_symlink
  purge_before_symlink.clear
  symlinks.clear
  symlinks {}
  notifies :restart, "service[abc]"
end
```